# How to send after filtered views result in mail in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I have created a view in drupal 7 with filters.. View is working fine I need to send after filter view result in mail with ajax views. 
This time I am not using ajax so I am sending a filtered url in mail..
But I need to use ajax views. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by

> I need to send after filter view result in mail with ajax views

If you need to send to the list of items (e.g., the items are members with email addresses), then you should install Rules, and set up Views Bulk Operations as described in [this Drupalize Me (i.e., Lulabot's teaching videos) series](https://drupalize.me/videos/views-bulk-operations-settings). Parts 18 through 21 describe how to take a view, and use Rules to make it do something like send an email.

If you'll expand a bit about what you're trying to do, I can be a bit more specific about this.

Comment: For example: I have two type filter age and rupee.. 
Age: 34,56,76 values. Rupee: 344$,123$,12$ etc. if i select 34 from and 123$ from rupees. then i got filtered data.. I need to send these filterered value. If I am not using ajax then easily send url .. but in the case using ajax .

Comment: So, you have a view with an exposed filter form with two drop downs, one for age, and one for (price?) in rupees.  when someone sets the drop downs and presses "Apply", you want an email to go out? If so, you can probably attach a javascript handler to the Apply button.  The handler would call an ajax handler on your site that sends an email.  That what you mean?

Comment: Here I dont need to use apply button,, I need to use auto submit.
after select any filter then we got filtered content.. I need to send this contetnt and selected filter in mail.